# YouTube Data API - Members: list Code 403

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The request https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/members fails with code 403 "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized." even in the Google OAuth 2.0 Playground while all other requests succeed. Does that mean I am missing the approval from YouTube? I have completed the forms to request the approval several weeks ago, but I have yet to get any response from  YouTube.

- API request with parameters used
  https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/members?part=snippet
- Result

```json
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.common",
    "message" : "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized."
}
```

- Expected result
  Response body with Members List
- Is it 100% reproducible?
  Yes
- Reproducible API explorer link
  https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: I think you forgot your question. is this supposed to be a bug report or something?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your quest describe your issue, include any code and or error messages.

Comment: Hello there! I have the same problem! Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

## approval

If you check the top of the page for
[members.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members/list) you will see that this method has been replaced by sponsors.list

[image: Note: The members.list method replaced the sponsors.list method as of March 31, 2020. This method can only be used with prior approval from YouTube. Please complete this form if your application needs to use this method.]

So calling Members.list isnt going to work.  You ened to call sponsors.list and you need permission from google inorder to call that

## authorization

Assuming you have summited the form and requested access to the new sponsors.list method and have been granted access you should know that calling memebers.list wont work. As its been deprecated you need to call sposors.list and it needs to be authorized. I would guess with the same scope as before.

[image]

The message is telling you that you have summited the request without being properly authorized to access the data.

> Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.

You need an access token sent as an authorization header before you will be able to make that call please check [authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)

As this new method isn't documented I would have to guess it would be something like this.

```
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/sponsors?part=snippet?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

If you have been granted access to this method then you might have an email contact at google that you can ask what the actual call is if its not working.

Comment: I know that and the request is authorized with the correct scope.
You can replicate this behaviour yourself here:
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

1. Select the youtube.channel-memberships.creator scope
2. Exchange authorization code for tokens
3. Request GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/members?part=snippet

Comment: sponsors list isnt on oauth playgroud as you need access to it.  members list isnt there either as its deprecated so im not sure what your doing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're getting it mixed up. Members.List is not deprecated, Sponsors.List is deprecated. Members.List is on the Google OAuth 2.0 Playground as it is listed in Step 3 under "List possible operations". My initial question was, is the response in my question the one you get when you're missing the approval from Google?

Comment: The response you are getting is the one from a lack of authorization either you are not sending your access token or they have not granted you access yet. Have you heard from them when did they grant you access?